# Find whether internet connection is present from tcl file

Tags: tcl

Hi I have an application written in tcl tk and I need to check if the internet connection is present in the machine the application will be running in from within the tcl code. Is there a way to know whether internet connection is present using tcl. Can you please help.

Comment: You can use a ping test, and there is a script [on the wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/16630), which looks quite easy to understand.

Comment: There's a few subtle ways a simple ping test can go wrong, especially with weird captive portals. This is an area where being _very_ clear about what you want to do will help.